# QML: horizontal scrolling tabs bar

Tags: qml, qtquick2, tabview, qt5.5, qtquickcontrols

Is it possible to set up horizontal scrolling tabs via `TabViewStyle` (or any different way)? I don't see such functionality in `TabViewStyle`. Moreover tabs scrolling shouldn't stop when tabs is displayed partially.

Answer (score 1):

With `TabBar` from Qt Quick Controls 2 (Qt 5.7+) it is possible to create [flickable tabs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html#flickable-tabs).